# Is it possible to calculate an exact/approximate expectation over an argmax function of a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

given a non-increasing vector $b\in R^n$, I would like to calculate the expected argmax of the function $f(b) = i \cdot b_i$ . More formally- Given a vector $b' \in \mathbb{R}^n $ each entry $b'_i$ is sampled from a distribution $F$. Let $b$ be the non-increasing order version of $b'$. Denote by $i^*:=argmax_{i\in [n]} \{i\cdot b_i\}$. What is $\mathbb{E}[i^*]$ ? 
It's worth mentioning that I assume that the vector $b$ is drawn from some known distribution $F$. All my attempts so far used the expected vector $b$, but I don't want to use this expected vector, but rather use the expectation on the whole term, Answers with (mathematical properties) limitations of $F$ (such as regularity or liphshiz) are also welcomed.

In mathematics, the arguments of the maxima (abbreviated arg max or argmax) are the points, or elements, of the domain of some function at which the function values are maximized. In contrast to global maxima, which refers to the largest outputs of a function, arg max refers to the inputs, or arguments, at which the function outputs are as large as possible.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Have you worked out the answer for, say, a uniform distribution on the unit interval as $F$, and the values $n = 2, 3$? That might give you (and us) some insight.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but maybe it provides a bit of insight. Consider a pair of numbers $(a, b)$ drawn from the unit square uniformly. After "sorting", we end up with $a \ge b$, hence a point $P = (x, y)$ in the triangle with vertices $A = (0,0), B = (1, 0), C = (1,1)$.

The problem is then to look at $(x, 2y)$ and ask which of $x$ and $2y$ is the larger. Well, if $x > 2y$, then $x$ is larger, and if $x < 2y$, then $2y$ is larger (duh). Points of the first type are those in the triangle $ABD$, where $D = (1, 0.5)$; points of the second type are those in the triangle $ADC$. Using $AB$ as the base for both, and $BD$ and $DC$ as the corresponding altitudes. Thus each area is $1/4$. And the expected value is $3/2$.

You can do something rather similar for $n = 3$, dividing a tetrahedron into six sub-tets, identifying the max value of $i x_i$ in each, and finding the volume of each to let you compute the expected value.

---

A quick test with a matlab program that generates and tests 100000 samples gives the following:

```
 n   E[i*]
 1    1
 2    1.4999
 3    2.0600
 4    2.6155
 5    3.1649
 6    3.7147
```

Presumably for $n = 3$, the actual answer is exactly $2$. After that, no particular pattern jumps out at me.

Here's the (not very pretty) code:

```
function mse018(n)
k = 100000;
u = rand(k, n);
u = sort(u, 2, 'descend');
v = repmat(1:n, k, 1);
uv = u .* v;
[m, I] = max(uv, [], 2);
n
mean(I)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very nice in informative solution! However, it seems difficult to extend this solution to a general $n>2$ one.